# VBA Userform ListBox and TextBox

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have the follow sub to find a cell based on three criteria.

```
Private Sub FindEstimate_Click()

Dim i As Long

i = 5
Do
    If Cells(i, 1) = TextBox1 And Cells(i, 6) = ListBox1 And Cells(i, 9) =  ListBox2 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Select
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop Until Cells(i, 1) = TextBox1 And Cells(i, 6) = ListBox1 And Cells(i, 9) = ListBox2

End Sub
```

It simply does not work, and I suspect it has something to do with the Loop Until statement.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check with `Cells(i, 6) = ListBox1` and `Cells(i, 9) = ListBox2` ? the `Selected` item in the `ListBox` ?

Comment: `Range.Find` is probably a better idea than looping.

Comment: I am trying to find the first cell of a row based on three criteria. First is estimate number (e.g. "8888" "8889"). Another is (column 6), is site (e.g. Facebook*, Twitter*, Pinterest*). Column 9 is month (6/16, 7/16-7/17).

Comment: I played around with it, and I simplified it to try to find the issue. I get a 1004 object defined error from the following line of code:                                                       
    Do Until Cells(i, 1) = TextBox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better of using the `Find` function, and loop through all `Find` results in Column "A" (in case there are multiple matches with `TextBox1.Value`), until you are able to find also a match with `ListBox1.Value` and `ListBox2.Value`.

For that you will use a `Do` <-> `Loop While Not FindRng Is Nothing And FindRng.Address <> FirstAddres` loop.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FindEstimate_Click()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim FirstRng As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String


Set Rng = Range("A5:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

With Rng
    Set FindRng = .Find(what:=Me.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)

    If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' find was successful
       ' Set FirstRng = FindRng
        FirstAddress = FindRng.Address

        Do
            If FindRng.Offset(, 5).Value = Me.ListBox1.Value And FindRng.Offset(, 8).Value = Me.ListBox2.Value Then
                FindRng.Select ' <-- not sure why you need to select it
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set FindRng = .FindNext(FindRng)
        Loop While Not FindRng Is Nothing And FindRng.Address <> FirstAddress

    Else ' Find faild to find the value in TextBox1
        MsgBox "Unable to find " & Me.TextBox1.Value & " at column A"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```